# Cosa significa "trinato" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto:

> Io me li gioco: si contenti, Artemisia, di quel che viene: oggi, il gruppo delle sue amiche fiorentine, sulla ghiaia aspretta del gran viale in salita, ognuna col suo nome -- Violante vedova, Giovanna Sorri, le due cognate Torrigiani, Caterina zitella -- ognuna con l'alto *trinato* rigido che s'impiglia alla nuca nei capellucci.

La mia domanda è sul significato del vocabolo "trinato" in questo brano. I dizionari lo definiscono come un aggettivo, ma qui sembra un sostantivo e non capisco qual è il suo senso.

Comment: Dal contesto un copricapo... ma non so di che foggia.

Comment: Comunque, visto che trina significa anche merletto, mi immagino uno di quei copricapi a fascia fatti ad uncinetto qualcosa come [questo](http://promessisposi.weebly.com/lucia.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L'aggettivo "alto" e il riferimento alla nuca, più che a un copricapo mi fanno pensare a un colletto (qui si parla di "collari di trina" diffusi dal Cinquecento e che potevano stare sollevati intorno al collo: http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/colletto_(Enciclopedia-Italiana)/).

Comment: Quindi, si tratterebbe di un colletto di trina, no?

Comment: Anche qui si parla di "colletti di trinato": https://books.google.es/books?id=uJZCAjSXbzcC&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61&dq=colletto+trinato&source=bl&ots=3Ifi_WIWDU&sig=RlpD8CNi_pI6-gNMXRjsPVVRN1o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj80sbL_dbKAhXFthQKHTrvA_A4ChDoAQgbMAg#v=onepage&q=trinato&f=false

Comment: Penso che potrebbe far riferimento a quello.

Comment: Anch'io penso che tu abbia ragione. Potresti scriverlo in modo un po' più chiaro nella risposta?